# Resuming completed downloads after rtorrent restart

Tags: rtorrent

For my rtorrent setup I have these folders

```
~/Session      //# rtorrent session
~/Torrent      //# torrent files
~/Incomplete   //# Downloading
~/Seeding      //# Completed download and seeding
~/Completed    //# Manually move completed (closed) torrents
```

In my .rtorrent.rc

```
session = ~/Session
## For readability, setting these:
# load_start=~/Torrent/*.torrent
# d.set_directory=~/Incomplete
# d.set_custom1=~/Seeding/
schedule = watch_directory_1,10,10,"load_start=~/Torrent/*.torrent,d.set_directory=~/Incomplete,d.set_custom1=~/Seeding/"

## On completion move to Seeding folder
system.method.set_key =event.download.finished,move_complete,"d.set_directory=$d.get_custom1= ;execute=mv,-u,$d.get_base_path=,$d.get_custom1="
```

If I have to restart rtorrent it tends to segfault with so I have to empty my session directory, but the completed torrents with data `~/Seeding` are seen as new and start to download again.

As per [this question](https://superuser.com/q/410507/42141) I can `ctrl-x` and enter `d.set_directory=~/Seeding` for each torrent but this command takes quite a while to run and to apply it to 100's of torrents is unfeasible.

Is there a way on adding a torrent to rtorrent that it can check if the data files already exist in the `~/Seeding` (`$d.set_custom1`) folder before downloading into `~/Incomplete` (`,d.set_directory`)?

**Versions**
I am running with libtorrent 0.13.3 & rtorrent 0.9.3 on installed via brew on OS X Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 1):

Use symlinks instead of set_directory, then the location is persisted outside of rTorrent and thus stable.